# Why do I haven't the keras.applications module?

Tags: python-2.7, keras

```html
from scipy.misc import imsave
import numpy as np
import time
from keras.applications import vgg16
from keras import backend as K
```

ImportError: No module named applications

I have installed Keras, and the other modules work well, 
why there is no "applications" module

Comment: What is your Keras version? (you can check with `keras.__version__`)

Comment: Yes, I check the version, and update them. The problem is solved with Keras 2.0.2 and theano 0.9. Thank you.

Comment: Try upgrading Keras,Keras-Application version.Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61547033/7355075) for help.

Comment: Try upgrading Keras,Keras-Application version.Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61547033/7355075) for help.

Answer (score 3):

Install Keras-Applications using

```
 pip install Keras-Applications
```