# How do I rectify the error ImportError: cannot import name 'MobileNet'?

Tags: keras, deep-learning

I am getting this error

I have installed keras and other required libraries but don't know why this error is coming

```
from keras.applications import MobileNet
```

> ImportError: cannot import name 'MobileNet'.

Comment: The problem is maybe with the keras verions. Try upgrading them
[using this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43071995/why-do-i-havent-the-keras-applications-module/61555897#61555897).

Answer (score 1):

You should import it as `from keras.applications.mobilenet import MobileNet`.

Comment: Already tried that,but no success.In jupyter notebook it  is giving additional error info as ImportError: No module named 'keras.applications.mobilenet' and in pycharm it is giving this error info -Cannot find reference 'MobileNet' in '__init__.py'

Comment: Are you using actual Keras? Or `tf.keras`? Can you aybe try installing `keras_applications` separately? `pip install keras_applications`

Comment: keras version 1.2.0

Comment: That's quite an old version, current version is 2.2.4. You can upgrade with `pip install --upgrade keras`.

Comment: Yes,in command prompt it is showing requirement already satisfied

Comment: Can  you `pip install keras==2.2.4`?

Comment: even after upgrading ,it is giving name error as NameError: name 'MobileNet' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer,If we are using  Keras 2.2.0 version, then we will not find the applications module inside keras installed directory. Keras has externalized the applications module to a separate directory called keras_applications from where all the pre-trained models will now get imported.

Comment: So, how do you import it then?

Comment: Yes, they externalized, but the imports don't change, there is code for that.

Comment: Yes, exactly, that's why I wonder for the actual answer to the question :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved by upgrading Keras,Keras-Application version.Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61547033/7355075) for help.