# I am not able to import resnet from keras.applications module

Tags: tensorflow, keras, resnet

I'm unable to import this module

```
import keras.applications.resnet
```

> ModuleNotFoundError
>    in ()
>   ----> 1 import keras.applications.resnet

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.applications.resnet'`

---

keras resnet [link](https://keras.io/applications/#resnet)

Answer (score 29):

Keras team hasn't included resnet, resnet_v2 and resnext in the current module, they will be added from Keras 2.2.5, as mentioned [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/12289).

For a workaround, you can use keras_applications module directly to import all ResNet, ResNetV2 and ResNeXt models, as given below

```
from keras_applications.resnet import ResNet50
```

Or if you just want to use ResNet50

```
from keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
```

Alternatively, you can always build from source as mentioned [here](https://keras.io/#installation).

Comment: @SuvigyaVijay I am trying your method, but I seem to be getting a NoneType function back? `mport keras_applications.resnet_v2 as resenet2
        return  resenet2.ResNet101V2`

Save the return to `base_model`

But if I call ` base_model(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)`, 

I get back `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'image_data_format'`

Comment: `keras_applications` doesn't seem to be compatible with eager execution, so I get an error when I try to use this in tf2.0: `"module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'get_default_graph'"`

Comment: I tried this and got `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.applications.resnet50'`

Answer (score 10):

try to use

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
```

Answer (score 6):

Found a workaround to use ResNeXt in Keras 2.2.4 [here](http://donghao.org/2019/02/22/using-resnext-in-keras-2-2-4/).

> ResNeXt50() function needs 4 more arguments: backend, layers, models and utils.

```
import keras
from keras_applications.resnext import ResNeXt50

model = ResNeXt50(weights='imagenet',
                  backend=keras.backend,
                  layers=keras.layers,
                  models=keras.models,
                  utils=keras.utils)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Keras there are multiple flavours of ResNet, you will have to specify the version of ResNet that you want e.g. You wish to load the ResNet50.

Use

`from keras.applications import ResNet50`

**Edit 2** This is the list you get when you use `dir()` command on applications

`['DenseNet121', 'DenseNet169', 'DenseNet201', 'InceptionResNetV2', 'InceptionV3', 'MobileNet', 'MobileNetV2', 'NASNetLarge', 'NASNetMobile', 'ResNet50', 'VGG16', 'VGG19', 'Xception', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'absolute_import', 'backend', 'densenet', 'division', 'inception_resnet_v2', 'inception_v3', 'keras_applications', 'keras_modules_injection', 'layers', 'mobilenet', 'mobilenet_v2', 'models', 'nasnet', 'print_function', 'resnet50', 'utils', 'vgg16', 'vgg19', 'xception']`, the models visible here can be laoded like this, There are some models like ResNet101 missing here, let me see if I can come up with a way to fix this.

**Edit** Proof that this works too

[image]

To see all the available versions of the Resnet models, visit https://keras.io/applications/#resnet

Comment: `resnet` modules available  inside `keras.applications.renset` not in `keras.applications`

Comment: @MohamedThasinah Just because what you know works doesn't mean that there is no other way to do it, check the edit in the answer above to look for proof. P.S. This is implemented in google Colab and summary has been cut-off, but I think it gets the message across.

Comment: ResNet50 will work can you try with ResNet101 with the same style and could you show your proof?

Comment: @MohamedThasinah Sorry for the confusion but I am pretty sure I mentioned ResNet50 in the example, but I get your point as well and it's a fair point, the answer has to be general, I will update accordingly.

Comment: Is this `from keras.applications.resnet import ResNet50` working for you? if so could you tell me? because I get stuck here. I'm unable to import `resnet` module :(

Comment: @MohamedThasinah Looks like  I have some Introspection to do.

Comment: yup me too, in case if you successfully import resnet101 please just let me know :)

Comment: @MohamedThasinah what is your Keras version?

Comment: @desertnaut- - i'm using keras 2.2.2

Answer (score 0):

Check the versions:

```
pip list | grep Keras
```

If it's already installed, uninstall and upgrade:

```
pip uninstall Keras
pip install Keras==2.3.1

pip uninstall Keras-Applications
pip install Keras-Applications==1.0.8

pip uninstall Keras-Preprocessing
pip install Keras-Preprocessing==1.1.0
```

Comment: I think it would be better to use "pip install --upgrade", as these versions have quickly become outdated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a python package named 'keras-resnet' which has ResNet50, ResNet101, ResNet152 and many more variants of ResNet. (https://pypi.org/project/keras-resnet/)

Installation is also quite easy. Just type

```
pip install keras-resnet
```

It will install this module and then use it like:

```
from keras_resnet.models import ResNet50, ResNet101, ResNet152

backbone = ResNet50(inputs=image_input, include_top=False, freeze_bn=True)
C2, C3, C4, C5 = backbone.outputs # this will give you intermediate 
# outputs of four blocks of resnet if you want to merge low and high level features
```

I am using backbones from this module and is working fine for me!

Comment: The project has no docs. Not very trustable/reliable

Answer (score 0):

```
from keras.applications.resnet
import ResNet101    

tf.keras.backend.clear_session
model=VGG19()
model.summary()


tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model,show_shapes=True)
visualkeras.layered_view(model,legend=True)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Before running

```
tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
```

you need to run

```
from tensorflow import keras
```