# Where is pretrained ResNet101 in Keras and how obtain raw feature?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, feature-extraction, resnet

I need pretrained ResNet101 in Keras but Python gives me error. In the documentation they write

```
keras.applications.resnet.ResNet101(include_top=True, weights='imagenet', input_tensor=None, input_shape=None, pooling=None, classes=1000)
```

(https://keras.io/applications/)
but when I import ResNet101 Python gives the error

```
AttributeError: module 'keras.applications' has no attribute 'resnet'
```

Moreover, I need the features calculated before the "pooling" layer, for example using VGG16 I'd do this:

```
myModel = Model(baseModel.input, baseModel.layers[-2].output)
```

How can I obtain them using ResNet?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in your Keras version:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54730330/9110938

**Feature Extraction**

Last two layers of ResNet-101 are global average pooling and fully-connected layers. Because of that:

```
myModel.layers[-1].output # output of the FC layer
myModel.layers[-2].output # output of the global average pooling layer
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
keras.applications.ResNet101(include_top=True, weights='imagenet', input_tensor=None, input_shape=None, pooling=None, classes=1000)
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack overflow. Don't just post code, but maybe try to explain in a few words why you think your answer solves the problem.