# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.applications.resnet50 on google colab

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, google-colaboratory, resnet

I am trying to run an image-based project on colab. I found the project on github. Everything runs fine till I reached the cell with the following code:

```
import keras
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input, ResNet50
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense, MaxPool2D, Conv2D
```

When I run it, the following output is observed:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-173cbce466d6> in <module>()
      1 import keras
      2 from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
----> 3 from keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input, ResNet50
      4 from keras.models import Model
      5 from keras.layers import Dense, MaxPool2D, Conv2D

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.applications.resnet50'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It's running 2.7.0 keras, connected to a TPU runtime. I tried !pip installing the said module but no use. I even tried running a demo resnet50 project too but got the same error. Can anyone please help me solve the error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I am not able to import resnet from keras.applications module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54682539/i-am-not-able-to-import-resnet-from-keras-applications-module)

Comment: I tried this, not luck. Only then i asked the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
```

Comment: I tried it and got this error: -------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-0b754e6afe0b> in <module>()
      1 import keras
      2 from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
----> 3 from tf.keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
      4 from keras.models import Model
      5 from keras.layers import Dense, MaxPool2D, Conv2D

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tf'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: I updated the answer. Also, make sure you installed tensorflow first. @Anonymous